# Change an image based on the time of day

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

I'm working on a website that contains many elements that change based on the time of day. I would like to have an image change based on the time of day, one image for a day period, and one for night, so:

Day image = 8:30–00:00

Night image = 00:00–8:30

I came across this example on Stackoverflow, but I'm not sure if this is accurate to my browser time (the image change should be based on my time and not the users).

This is the example:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    SetImage();
    window.setInterval(SetImage,1000);
});

function SetImage(){     
    var nowdate = new Date() ;
    
    var waketime = new Date();     
    waketime.setHours(6);
    waketime.setMinutes(30);
    
    var bedtime = new Date();     
    bedtime.setHours(18);
    bedtime.setMinutes(30);
    
    if(waketime < nowdate  && nowdate < bedtime){
         $('#day').show();
         $('#night').hide();
    }else{
         $('#night').show();
         $('#day').hide();
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="night" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_7-b4ZWNPaD8/TThuPK0cvUI/AAAAAAAAAAQ/jCqRshKkJd4/s1600/night-scene.jpg">
<img id="day" src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Events/Independence%20Day/independence-day-67a.jpg">
```

Any ideas? Any help would be fantastic. Thank you :-)

Comment: You time, not the user's time? than use the servers time +/- your time difference. Take a look at PHP or Node.js or any other server-side language. Perhaps you can look for some API that serves your exact time using AJAX...

Comment: What do you mean by "your time"? Do you mean the server's time?

Comment: Why do you want to call your function every second when you want to change the picture every 8.5+ hours?

Comment: Ah yes, so I would like the image change to be based on my location which is Central European Time. My server located is in America so I need a way to make the change based on Amsterdam or Brussels time.

Comment: you're going to need `Date.getUTCxxxxx`, `Date.setUTCxxxxx` and `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` to do this correctly. I don't have the time to try but it should help you get started. Also using CSS to hide the images might be just a touch faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side you check time and based on it, you add either night or day to the body (as class or data attribute)

Additionally, you can run your script and update it if a user doesn't reload.

```js
window.setInterval(SetImage,5000);   /* set this to at least 10 min */

function SetImage(){     
    var nowdate = new Date();    
    var waketime = new Date();     
    waketime.setHours(6);
    waketime.setMinutes(30);
    
    var bedtime = new Date();     
    bedtime.setHours(18);
    bedtime.setMinutes(30);
    
    if(waketime < nowdate  && nowdate < bedtime) {
         document.body.setAttribute('data-daytime','');
    }else{
         document.body.setAttribute('data-nighttime','');
    }
}
```

```css
.toggletime {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
}
body[data-nighttime] .toggletime {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body data-daytime>
  <div class="toggletime">
    Hey there
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Client Time :**

If you are talking about the client time, that's good. But I recommand to change the interval used to 10 min or more.

**Server Time:**

But If you are talking about the server time, the response will be no. You have to pass the time of your server by a backend code like php,java,node... **Or**, you can use time given api, like this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function myCallback(json) {
    alert(new Date(json.dateString));
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://timeapi.org/utc/after+one+hour.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

This work only if you use JSONP. What we do is we request this url that contains the time of your server (in Amsterdam): http://www.timeapi.org/utc/after+one+hour

Comment: Sorry I wasn't so clear in my original question as to what time I want to show. I would like the image change to be based on my location which is Central European Time. My server located is in America so I need a way to make the change based on Amsterdam or Brussels time.